# Cisco MIB for physical memory

Tags: cisco

```
router#show ver

4194304K bytes of physical memory.
```

Does anyone know the mib for physical memory of a cisco router?  Lots of examples of memory used etc.

Edit:

Nothing is easy in cisco land

```
-sh-4.1$ snmpwalk -v2c -c r2 router 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.195.1.1.1.1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.195.1.1.1.1.7000 = Gauge32: 1845398136

-sh-4.1$ snmpwalk -v2c -c r2 router 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.3.6.6
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.3.6.6.0 = INTEGER: 790666272

Router# sh ver
4194304K bytes of physical memory.
```

Both appear to be different?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

`OLD-CISCO-CHASSIS-MIB::processorRam` But that MIB has been deprecated since IOS 12.0.

```
-- *****************************************************************
-- OLD-CISCO-CHASSIS-MIB.my:  Cisco Chassis MIB file
--
--
-- May 1994, Jeffrey T. Johnson
--
-- Copyright (c) 1994-2008 by cisco Systems, Inc.
-- All rights reserved.
--
-- NOTE WELL
-- Starting with IOS 12.0, all objects defined in this mib have been
-- deprecated.  They have been replaces with objects defined in the
-- ENTITY-MIB.my document. Management applications should no longer
-- be examining the objects defined in this document.
-- NOTE WELL
-- 
-- *****************************************************************
```

`CISCO-ENTITY-EXT-MIB::ceExtProcessorRam` is where they moved it. (7 years later.)

---

From my 2851:

```
Cisco 2851 (revision 1.0) with 1032192K/16384K bytes of memory.
CISCO-ENTITY-EXT-MIB::ceExtProcessorRam.3 = Gauge32: 1073741824 bytes
OLD-CISCO-CHASSIS-MIB::processorRam.0 = INTEGER: 1056964608
```

The entity mib is processor + io memory (all physical ram), and the old chassis mib is showing just the processor memory (as the name suggests)

If the service-engine is configured, then physical memory is partitioned, and it may not be reflected in SNMP.

Comment: Strange that I get 2 different values.  Free memory?